# cluetip tooltip flicker when over image

Tags: jquery, css

I have placed a cluetip tooltip over an image and added html links to the cluetip by an external file. I am trying to get the cluetip to open on mouse over the image and then close when mouse out of the image. This all works except for the cluetip flickers as I move the mouse over the cluetip/image as i select one of the three buttons...

These must be a way to do this, if anyone can help me Thanks

I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(\'a.tips\').cluetip({
    width: 80,
    topOffset: -45,
    leftOffset:-90,
    positionBy: \'fixed\',
    cluetipClass:     \'rounded\',
    showTitle:        false,
    sticky:           true, 
    mouseOutClose:    true
      });  
});
```

What would be good is to use sticky 'true' with mouse out close, but I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually adding [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) fixes flickering issues. I haven't used cuetip before, but try something like:

```
$(\'a.tips\').stop().cluetip({ ... });
```